# How to restore IDLE to factory settings

Tags: python, settings, reset, restore, python-idle

I was messing with the Preferences in Python IDLE and I couldn't edit the size of the window. So I right clicked on the windows size where it says "Width and Height" and got a ridiculous size for width!

Now IDLE wont even turn on. I tried uninstalling it and installing it again but it doesn't work. I have a Mac. How do I reset IDLE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you mean Idle (which comes with Python), close Idle, then in Terminal, type:

```
mv ~/.idlerc ~/.idlerc-save
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Environment: Idle 3, Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

I know you're using Mac, but here's how to reset WinPython's IDLEX:

Go to the install location -> open `settings` -> rename `.idlerc` to `idlerc.bak`

Note: If you want to restore it, Windows will not let you rename `idlerc.bak` back to `.idlerc`. So you will need to launch IDLEX, close it, then copy the files from `idlerc.bak` into `.idlerc`.