# How to restore factory settings IDLE python IDE

Tags: python, python-idle

I have been messing around with idle and i accidentally broke some graphic settings and i wanted to restore it to default, i have tried following answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17328538/how-to-restore-idle-to-factory-settings) but the answer for windows did not work, i think it was for another version of python. Anyone have a solution?

Comment: Removing or renaming .idlerc removes all the user customizations reflected in the options dialog.  This directly applies to all python and IDLE versions for a particular user.  I don't know what other 'graphic settings' you might have changed.   To echo ocelot, what does 'not work' mean?

Answer (score 0):

What error occurred exactly?

If the worst comes to the worst you may be better off completely removing Python(*) from the Control Panel and reinstalling it from [the python website.](http://www.python.org/)

This'll allow you to both reset IDLE to factory settings and add python to PATH if you missed that option or anything during setup.