# Does anyone know the default font for Python IDLE on Macs?

Tags: python, python-idle

I've searched everywhere for the default font for the Python IDLE app when it was first downloaded. I changed it to Courier New because it was the default Windows font but then I can't remember what the original font was.

Comment: I think it's Monaco

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to restore IDLE to factory settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17328538/how-to-restore-idle-to-factory-settings)

Answer (score 0):

It is always  Courier New but I'm using Jetbrain Mono NL. I highly recommended that or Monaco.